# How to solve 'Error: expect 2, got 1' if I can only Input one value?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a newbie in programming and I am doing my python assignment. Sorry if my problem is silly.

I was asked to Write a python program for a two-player rolling dice game.
Each player has a counter to record their scores. Each time, a player would roll two dice. The sum of the two dice would be added to the corresponding player’s counter. If the player rolls doubles, then the player can continue to roll the dice. Otherwise, it would be the other player’s turn. When the input is 0, print the players’ scores.

Example input and output:

INPUT:

```
12 
31
23
0
```

OUTPUT:
**P1:8 P2:4**

ERROR message:
**not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)**

*Since this assignment is beginner-level, some complicated languages and functions are not allowed. Only list, dictionary, loop, and other basic languages are allowed

```
p1score = 0
p2score = 0
while True:
    p1roll1, p1roll2 = list(input())
    if p1roll1 == 0:
        print(f'P1:{plscore} P2:{p2score}')
        break
    elif p1roll1 == p1roll2:
        p1score += int(p1roll1) + int(p1roll2)
        continue
    elif p1roll1 != p1roll2:
        continue
    
    p2roll1, p2roll2 = list(input())
    if p2roll1 == 0:
        print(f'P1:{p1score} P2:{p2score}')
        break
    elif p2roll1 == p2roll2:
        p2score += int(p2roll1) + int(p2roll2)
        continue
    elif p2roll1 != p2roll2:
        continue
```

This is my code now. However, since '0' needed to be input to end the game, a single input cannot satisfy the requirement of input and an error pops out.

Is there any way to solve this? Or am I needed to rewrite the whole thing?

Comment: Please add all code as text, also add the full error message, as text

Comment: `input()` returns a string, so you would need to check equality with `'0'`.

Comment: `input` returns a string and that is a problem for two reasons. first `list(input()))` will be a list of the characters typed/ Second `p1roll1` even if it was the "first" number is again a string so never equal to 0

Comment: You must divide the input on the space: `list(input())` -> `input().split()`

Comment: Sadly I can't use `.split( )`  in this assignment :(

Comment: regarding the integer problem, I can just add `int( )` before `p1roll1` and it can change it from a list to an integer?

Comment: The input doesn't need `list()` or `split()` at all.  I edited the question to more clearly show that each pair of dice rolls is represented by a single two-digit number on a separate line of input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accept the input into a plain variable *before* you do any special processing on it.

```
while True:
    answer = input()
    if answer == "0":
        break
    p1roll1, p1roll2 = answer
```

Comment: sorry if I get it wrong, isn't `print(f'P1:{plscore} P2:{p2score}')` should be added before break?

Comment: @Gr1mMount Yes, if you want to print the scores before quitting, then add the print statement.